# GitHub Actions workflow incorrectly shows successful run

Tags: r, github-actions

I have a GitHub Actions workflow run that shows an error at https://github.com/wlandau/targets-minimal/runs/2495052696#step:12:11 but still shows the green check mark to indicate success. How should I modify the [YAML file](https://github.com/wlandau/targets-minimal/blob/main/.github/workflows/targets.yaml) to make these errors correctly translate to a failed job?

[image]

Comment: You are using `continue-on-error: true` in your step "Run targets pipeline" which flags the step with a green check and allows the job to continue when there's an error. Maybe you want to remove this?